# Camera horizontal shift

Tags: camera, perspective

I want stretch my game on two monitors. I use Unity 5.3. This version support the multi-display. But, one camera = one monitor. 
So, have two perspective cameras (at the same position).  I search a "camera horizontal shift" option for create stretch effect. I don't find this option. Is-there a trick ? A solution ?

Comment: You can shift the offset of the rendered frame using an [oblique frustum](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ObliqueFrustum.html)

Comment: @ DMGregory : It's perfect ;)

Comment: If that solved the problem, feel free to write up your method as an answer & accept it. I don't know enough about multi-monitor rendering myself to give a complete solution myself.

Answer (score 1):

Yea, once I did this adventure. I can tell you what ever I can recall. Place 2 cameras with different `Viewport Rect` settings. On first camera, set `X` to `0` and `W` to `0.5` and on second one set `X` to `0.5` and `W` to `0.5`. Just like pictures given below. And attach some script to resize camera to full screen(You can try it later. First give a try without it). This could be your starting point. You can play further. :)

[image: Camera1]

[image: Camera2]